# C# 2.0 Multi-threading with a plug-in architecture

Tags: c#, multithreading, plugins

I have a well established console application in c# 2.0 that uses plugin architecture.
As of right now, the program uses basic multi-threading that can run several instances. The threads are created and continue on until the application is stopped.

Each instance can load its own variety of plugins and configured separately.
Plugins are inherited from a base plugin. This system has been working like a charm for years.
The plugins are event driven, they all read various events to see if they are called upon, if not they return and let the next plugin read the events to see if they are called out to fire.

This system has been working for years. However, I would like to further the scope of multi-threading to allow the plugins to listen to the events in an asynchronous fashion rather than synchronous. One of the drawbacks of this setup is that once a plugin fires and does its work, it locks out the instance. When the next event is fired it has to wait for the previous work to be completed. Then it will allow the next process to take place.

What I would like it to do, is execute the plugin and not have to wait for the process to end before moving on to the next process to begin by an event.

I am stuck with .Net 2.0 for the time being, and must find a solution in that framework. I have looked at numerous examples and I can not find one that meets the criteria. One of the problems is that each plugin has its own time that it may take to process, and there is no way to count to track the percentage that the plugin is complete. The plugins will start and ends its process when it is done. Depending on the parameters of the event, and the plugin it can take any range of time to complete.

My question would be what would be the best way to handle multi-threading in this situation where plugins are executed by events. I have looked at pages such as [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and I can figure out where I would be able to have an entry point in an event driven plugin architecture.

If anyone has any clue, I would appreciate it. The lack of multi-threading in this manner has been the Achilles' heel for this application for years.

Plugin base: These contain some functions that are triggered by events:

```
using System;
using VhaBot.Communication;

namespace VhaBot
{

/// <summary>
///     Plugin BaseClass, must be inherited by all plugins
/// </summary>
public abstract class PluginBase : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private bool _locked;
    private string _name;
    private string _internalName;
    private int _version;
    private string _author;
    private string[] _contributors;
    private string _description;
    private PluginState _defaultState;
    private string[] _dependencies;
    private Command[] _commands;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Friendly display name of plugin
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///  this.Name = "Message of the Day";
    ///   </code>
    /// </example>
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            if (_locked)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            _name = value;
        }
        get { return _name; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Internal name of the plugin
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///  this.InternalName = "VhMotd";
    ///   </code>
    /// </example>
    public string InternalName
    {
        set
        {
            if (_locked)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            _internalName = value.ToLower();
        }
        get { return _internalName; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Pluigin Version
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     Versions are stored as integers only. Version 1.0.0 would have a value of 100
    /// </remarks>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    /// this.Version = 100;
    ///  </code>
    /// </example>
    public int Version
    {
        set
        {
            if (_locked)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            _version = value;
        }
        get { return _version; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Author of the plugin
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    /// this.Author = "Vhab";
    ///  </code>
    /// </example>
    public string Author
    {
        set
        {
            if (_locked)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            _author = value;
        }
        get { return _author; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     List of contributors to the development of the plugin.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///  this.Contributors = new string[] { "Iriche", "Kilmanagh" };
    ///   </code>
    /// </example>
    public string[] Contributors
    {
        set
        {
            if (_locked)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            _contributors = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if (_contributors != null)
            {
                return _contributors;
            }
            return new string[0];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Description of the plugin
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///  this.Description = "Provides an interface to the user to view who is online and/or on the private channel.";
    ///   </code>
    /// </example>
    public string Description
    {
        set
        {
            if (_locked)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            _description = value;
        }
        get { return _description; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The default <see cref="VhaBot.PluginState" /> of the plugin
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    /// this.DefaultState = PluginState.Installed;
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <seealso cref="VhaBot.PluginState" />
    public PluginState DefaultState
    {
        set
        {
            if (_locked)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            _defaultState = value;
        }
        get { return _defaultState; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     List of other plugins that a plugin is dependent on to function
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     Plugins are referred to using their internal names. See <see cref="VhaBot.PluginBase.InternalName" />
    /// </remarks>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    /// this.Dependencies = new string[] { "vhItems" };
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public string[] Dependencies
    {
        set
        {
            if (_locked)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            _dependencies = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if (_dependencies != null)
            {
                return _dependencies;
            }
            return new string[0];
        }
    }

      public Command[] Commands
    {
        set
        {
            if (_locked)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            _commands = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if (_commands != null)
            {
                return _commands;
            }
            return new Command[0];
        }
    }

    internal void Init()
    {
        _locked = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     A plugin has loaded in response to <see cref="VhaBot.ShellModules.Plugins.Load" />
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// ///
    /// <remarks>Code inside this method will be executed when a plugin is loading</remarks>
    public virtual void OnLoad(BotShell bot)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     A plugin has unloaded in response to <see cref="VhaBot.ShellModules.Plugins.Unload" />
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// <remarks>Code inside this method will be executed when a plugin is unloading</remarks>
    public virtual void OnUnload(BotShell bot)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     A plugin has installed in response to <see cref="VhaBot.ShellModules.Plugins.Install" />
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    public virtual void OnInstall(BotShell bot)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     A plugin as been uninstalled in response to <see cref="VhaBot.ShellModules.Plugins.Uninstall" />
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    public virtual void OnUninstall(BotShell bot)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     A plugin has been upgraded (Unused)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// <param name="version"></param>
    /// <remarks>This function is not active</remarks>
    public virtual void OnUpgrade(BotShell bot, Int32 version)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Response to a command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public virtual void OnCommand(BotShell bot, CommandArgs e)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Response to an unauthorized command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public virtual void OnUnauthorizedCommand(BotShell bot, CommandArgs e)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Response to a command help query <see cref="VhaBot.ShellModules.Commands.GetHelp." />
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// <param name="command"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks>Code inside this method will be executed when help is requested</remarks>
    public virtual string OnHelp(BotShell bot, string command)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Response to a custom configuration
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual string OnCustomConfiguration(BotShell bot, string key)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Response to a plugin message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public virtual void OnPluginMessage(BotShell bot, PluginMessage message)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Response to a bot message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public virtual void OnBotMessage(BotShell bot, BotMessage message)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns display name of bot and current version
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " v" + Version;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     There is no information to document this command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bot"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    public void FireOnCommand(BotShell bot, CommandArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Authorized)
                OnCommand(bot, args);
            else
                OnUnauthorizedCommand(bot, args);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CommandArgs e = args;
            var window = new RichTextWindow(bot);
            window.AppendTitle("Error Report");

            window.AppendHighlight("Error: ");
            window.AppendNormal(ex.Message);
            window.AppendLinkEnd();
            window.AppendLineBreak();

            window.AppendHighlight("Source: ");
            window.AppendNormal(ex.Source);
            window.AppendLinkEnd();
            window.AppendLineBreak();

            window.AppendHighlight("Target Site: ");
            window.AppendNormal(ex.TargetSite.ToString());
            window.AppendLinkEnd();
            window.AppendLineBreak();

            window.AppendHighlight("Stack Trace:");
            window.AppendLineBreak();
            window.AppendNormal(ex.StackTrace);
            window.AppendLinkEnd();
            window.AppendLineBreak();

            bot.SendReply(e,
                          "There has been an error while executing this command »» " +
                          window.ToString("More Information"));
            BotShell.Output("[Plugin Execution Error] " + ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Events Class:

```
 namespace VhaBot.ShellModules
{
/// <summary>
///     VhaBot Events
/// </summary>
public class Events
{
    public event BotStateChangedHandler BotStateChangedEvent;
    public event ChannelJoinEventHandler ChannelJoinEvent;

    public event UserJoinChannelHandler UserJoinChannelEvent;
    public event UserLeaveChannelHandler UserLeaveChannelEvent;

    public event UserLogonHandler UserLogonEvent;
    public event UserLogoffHandler UserLogoffEvent;

    public event PrivateMessageHandler PrivateMessageEvent;
    public event PrivateChannelMessageHandler PrivateChannelMessageEvent;
    public event ChannelMessageHandler ChannelMessageEvent;

    public event MemberAddedHandler MemberAddedEvent;
    public event MemberRemovedHandler MemberRemovedEvent;
    public event MemberUpdatedHandler MemberUpdatedEvent;

    public event AltAddedHandler AltAddedEvent;
    public event AltRemovedHandler AltRemovedEvent;

    /// <summary>
    ///     A message was sent to the IRC channel in response to a <see      cref="VhaBot.BotShell.SendIrcMessage" /> request
    /// </summary>
    public event IrcMessageHandler IrcMessageEvent;

    public event ConfigurationChangedHandler ConfigurationChangedEvent;


    internal void OnBotStateChanged(BotShell bot, BotStateChangedArgs e)
    {
        if (BotStateChangedEvent != null)
            try
            {
                BotStateChangedEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnChannelJoin(BotShell bot, ChannelJoinEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChannelJoinEvent != null)
            try
            {
                ChannelJoinEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnUserJoinChannel(BotShell bot, UserJoinChannelArgs e)
    {
        if (UserJoinChannelEvent != null)
            try
            {
                UserJoinChannelEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnUserLeaveChannel(BotShell bot, UserLeaveChannelArgs e)
    {
        if (UserLeaveChannelEvent != null)
            try
            {
                UserLeaveChannelEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnUserLogon(BotShell bot, UserLogonArgs e)
    {
        if (UserLogonEvent != null)
            try
            {
                UserLogonEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnUserLogoff(BotShell bot, UserLogoffArgs e)
    {
        if (UserLogoffEvent != null)
            try
            {
                UserLogoffEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnPrivateMessage(BotShell bot, PrivateMessageArgs e)
    {
        if (PrivateMessageEvent != null)
            try
            {
                PrivateMessageEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnPrivateChannelMessage(BotShell bot, PrivateChannelMessageArgs e)
    {
        if (PrivateChannelMessageEvent != null)
            try
            {
                PrivateChannelMessageEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnChannelMessage(BotShell bot, ChannelMessageArgs e)
    {
        if (ChannelMessageEvent != null)
            try
            {
                ChannelMessageEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnMemberAdded(BotShell bot, MemberAddedArgs e)
    {
        if (MemberAddedEvent != null)
            try
            {
                MemberAddedEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnMemberRemoved(BotShell bot, MemberRemovedArgs e)
    {
        if (MemberRemovedEvent != null)
            try
            {
                MemberRemovedEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnMemberUpdated(BotShell bot, MemberUpdatedArgs e)
    {
        if (MemberUpdatedEvent != null)
            try
            {
                MemberUpdatedEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnAltAdded(BotShell bot, AltAddedArgs e)
    {
        if (AltAddedEvent != null)
            try
            {
                AltAddedEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnAltRemoved(BotShell bot, AltRemovedArgs e)
    {
        if (AltRemovedEvent != null)
            try
            {
                AltRemovedEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnConfigurationChanged(BotShell bot, ConfigurationChangedArgs e)
    {
        if (ConfigurationChangedEvent != null)
            try
            {
                ConfigurationChangedEvent(bot, e);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
    }

    internal void OnIrcMessage(BotShell bot, IrcMessageArgs e)
    {
        if (IrcMessageEvent != null)
        {
            IrcMessageEvent(bot, e);
        }
        try
        {
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So. just of clarify what you need.
You want a Architecture that allows you to execute multiple plugins at the same time? cause the plugins handel the events by them self.

Comment: "What I would like it to do, is execute the plugin and not have to wait for the process to end before moving on to the next process to begin by an event." So what is stopping you from doing this?  I don't see where you describe the reason why each plugin can't run in its own thread.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't say it couldn't be done, I am just trying to figure out HOW to do it. I have not used this style of multi-threading before.

Comment: Maybe we can start with the simplest example.  Say you were to replace each instance of `myPlugin.DoSomething();` with `Thread workerThread = new Thread(myPlugin.DoSomething); workerThread.Start();`.  Can you explain what is different about your situation that doesn't allow you to do this?

Comment: I just want to make sure I do it right. How it works, there are 2 different kind of events. The first type (as shown above) is fired within the plugin base (load, unload, oncommand.). The second set is derived from an API. Those events must be added to the plugin where the plugin consumes the event. All plugins use the events from the plugin base, however, each plugin may or may not listen to every API event. Those events are fired via shell modules and not via the plugin base.  OnChannelJoin,OnUserLogon, etc.

Comment: Plugins use:  public override void OnLoad(BotShell bot) to access the plugin events. For the API events, bot.Events.UserLogonEvent += UserLogonEvent; is used.

Answer (score 1):

I've got little to go on as your description of the system is a bit vague but I'll give it a shot.

From your description it seems you have some plugin, say

```
interface IPlugin {
   PluginResult ReadAndExecuteEvents(Events e);

   // Added asynchronous methods.
   IAsyncResult BeginReadAndExecuteEvents(Events e, AsyncCallback cb, Object state);
   PluginResult EndReadAndExecuteEvents(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

with

```
class PluginResult 
{
    public Boolean Stop;
    // etc.
}
```

also you don't seem to be using .NET *events*, but rather some sort of `Event` class/enumeration.

Your old code seems to be something like:

```
   foreach (var eventList in ReadEvents())
           foreach (var plugin in pluginList)
              if (plugin.ReadAndExecuteEvents(eventList).Stop)
                 break;
```

You can make this asynchronous doing something like:

```
 foreach (var eventList in ReadEvents())
     {
        // It seems this is what you want, only one event processed at a time by an "instance"? So block here until unlocked.
        LockProcess();

        var pluginIndex = 0;
        AsyncCallback handleResult = null;
        handleResult = delegate(IAsyncResult result)
        {
           if (pluginList[pluginIndex].EndReadAndExecuteEvents(result).Stop)
              goto STOP;

           pluginIndex += 1;

           if (pluginIndex == pluginList.Count)
              goto STOP;

           Events e = (Events)result.AsyncState;

           pluginList[pluginIndex].BeginReadAndExecuteEvents(e, handleResult, e);
           return;

        STOP:
           UnlockProcess();
        };

        pluginList[0].BeginReadAndExecuteEvents(eventList, handleResult, eventList);
     }
```

So in .NET 2 style you could add some BeginXxx method and in its AsyncCallback do your stuff. 
Of course it is up to the actual *plugin* to do its multithreading/asynchronisity, say if it writes a file by using `BeginWrite` to a `FileStream` etc.

I have conveniently ignored exception handling here.

So, to make your whole application use this asynchronisity you can put this code in a `BeginRunEvents` method, say, following the same "APM" pattern. You can then schedule this to the threadpool if you wish.

If this is not at all what you are looking for please provide some more code examples/info.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I can do is send you a link of my repository and see if I explained everything correctly.

Comment: I just updated with the plugin base and the events class source code.